# Using MongoDB with Rails - Any Good Articles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I'm hearing a lot recently about NoSQL databases, particularly MongoDB. I'm  interested to know what the implications of changing to a MongoDB database is within the context of a Ruby on Rails appplication.

I haven't been able to find an article that gives a good description of how things vary from using an SQL database when using MongoDB.

Do we still have database migrations? Relationships? Will `has_one` still work? What are the current adapters like?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the mongotips blog too

http://mongotips.com/

it explain a lot of thing about what MongoDb is awesome

Answer (score 4):

there is an article on mongodb's website: [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MongoDB+Data+Modeling+and+Rails)

Answer (score 3):

Railscasts has some episodes on MongoDB & Rails:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/238-mongoid

http://railscasts.com/episodes/194-mongodb-and-mongomapper

Answer (score 1):

This is a better site: http://mongomapper.com/documentation/getting-started/rails.html